# gradle - can't find reference to layout and file

Tags: gradle

reading the gradle's documentation, I came across this line of code:

`def archivesDirPath = layout.buildDirectory.dir('archives')`

Where in the gradle's documentation can I find a reference to the `layout` type, or for the `file` type?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: [ProjectLayout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ProjectLayout.html)

> An instance of this type can be injected into a task, plugin or other object by annotating a public constructor or method with javax.inject.Inject. It is also available via Project.getLayout().